# Target a single terraform module and its dependencies using terragrunt

Tags: terragrunt

Terragrunt allows us to execute terraform commands on multiple modules at once ([1]). 
However sometimes we want to target a single module and its dependencies in order to create and apply a plan for those modules only.

This would look like

```
terragrunt -target backend-app plan-all
```

where backend-app is an example name of s module we are targeting.

Is there a way to achieve that with terragrunt cli?

[1] - https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt#execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terragrunt has global options that are not passed down to terraform ([1]).

This did the trick:

```
terragrunt plan-all --terragrunt-include-dir "backend-app"
```

There are other options that can be combined to achieve even finer selections.

[1] - https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt#cli-options